# I am getting a Type Error with - "$ is not a function" when using noConflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a Dashboard UI and I incorporated so many Js components. Previously it was working fine (mainly the Data Table) and now I did some Form components switch and check box. I am getting a Type Error with - jQuery is not a function using no-conflict.

Although I have tried all suggestion posted on StackOverflow but none of the solutions work and getting same problem while using no-conflict.

Current issues is my Data Table is not working ...

**[Click Here for the test Page](http://webapplications.co.in/emr/dashboard.html)**

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
var oTable = $('#ActiveMedicalProblems').dataTable({
```

The Script is in my Data Table

```
var oTable = $('#ActiveMedicalProblems').dataTable({
            "aLengthMenu": [
                [5, 15, 20, -1],
                [5, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
            ],
            // set the initial value
            "iDisplayLength": 5,
            "sDom": "<'row'<'col-lg-6'l><'col-lg-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-lg-6'i><'col-lg-6'p>>",
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sPrevious": "Prev",
                    "sNext": "Next"
                }
            },
            "aoColumnDefs": [{
                    'bSortable': false,
                    'aTargets': [0]
                }
            ]
        });
```

And the script in my page is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          ActiveMedicalProblems.init();
      });
```

I have tried with other methods but no luck.

```
(function($){
   ActiveMedicalProblems.init();
});
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(jQuery)`?

Comment: No conflict says "don't assign a global $". Something was expecting `$` to be available in the [global] scope (in this case, that looks like *your* code), instead of using the suggested approach of `(function ($) .. )(jQuery)`. [This is covered in the documentation.](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: Not saying this is the issue, but you appear to be using jQuery v1.10.2. That's a rather old version of the library. Consider upgrading to the latest version asap or you'll be left in the dust and newer plugins will/might not work as expected. Current *stable* release is 2.2.3: https://jquery.com/download/

Comment: check whether the reference to JQuery library is set properly. a good idea is to try with an simple alert. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either cut the `noConflict` call - this will be a short-term solution and make all code work again.

Alternatively, wrap the "Data Table" code (not the invocation), like this:

```
(function($) {
var oTable = $('#ActiveMedicalProblems').dataTable({
...
})(jQuery);
```

However, you won't be able to define global names then. Far easier is probably to simply replace every instance of `$` with `jQuery`. Your code will be a little bit longer, but it will be unambiguous.